# "Connection Refused" Error When Consuming Messages in Go Application Deployed in Docker

Tags: go, stomp

I am encountering an issue with consuming messages using a Go application. The message broker service is running in a Java application on my local Tomcat server, which produces topics. In my Go application, I'm using the STOMP library to consume these topics. However, when I attempt to connect, I'm receiving the following error:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:61616: connect: connection refused.
```

The same messages I am able to receive in Java but not from Go. I have deployed my Go project within a Docker container.

```golang
import (
    "github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3"
)

func main() {

    conn, error := stomp.Dial("tcp", "localhost:61616")

    fmt.Println("Printing conn 2 ", error.Error())
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this has nothing to do with ActiveMQ and everything to do with your environment.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that port `61616` is for OpenWire clients not STOMP clients.

Comment: You should elaborate on how you're running Docker and how the broker is configured to receive connections. Just because you have a Docker container running on your local machine doesn't mean it can necessarily access anything outside that container via the network.

Comment: Any library for OpenWire clients in go lang?

Comment: For an application written in Go I would recommend using STOMP. It is a simple and effective messaging protocol with good support across lots of platforms and languages.

Comment: Am new to message broker concept, broker is already configured successfully in Java language and deployed in tomcat, but am really not sure if anything to be done in go lang apart from just connecting to it.

Comment: The first rule of networked client-server architectures is that the client must be able to connect to the server via the network. Given that your client is reporting "connection refused" that indicates it can't reach the server over the network. I recommend simplifying your environment by eliminating Docker. Running everything directly on your "bare metal" will give it a better chance of working.

Answer (score 1):

A `connection refused` indicates that the Go application is not able to reach the STOMP server over the network. This is almost certainly a problem in your environment (e.g. networking between your Docker container and the broker).

Comment: Broker and my docker container both are running in my local. Am really not sure what could be the network problem here. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your Go application could reach the broker over the network then you wouldn't get "connection refused."